# grab 'environmentVariables' with a tag

Tags: config, multi-environment

```
'dev' => array(
        'siteUrl' => array(
            'de_ch' => 'http://blabla.dev/',
            'en' => 'http://blabla.dev/en/',
        ),
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => 'path',
            'baseUrl' => 'http://url-without-locale-segment.dev/',
        )
    ),
```

I set a `baseUrl` inside `environmentVariables` to be able to grab the url without a locale. But when I enter `{{ baseUrl }}` in the template it returns an error:

> Variable "baseUrl" does not exist

How do I have to write this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get to any of your config variables (including custom ones) like this:

```twig
{{ craft.config.xyz }}
```

The environmentVariables array is no different:

```twig
{{ craft.config.environmentVariables.baseUrl }}
```

See the [craft.config](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.config) documentation.

Comment: Cool. Thank you :)

Comment: Also, if you wanted to use the shorter version of `{{ baseUrl }}`, you could also add `{% set baseUrl = craft.config.environmentVariables.baseUrl %}` at the top of your template.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use envVars as you would in the control panel i.e. `{baseUrl}` but, in your templates, then check out the [Filter Environment Variables](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-filterenvvar/) plugin.

> Just apply the `envvar` filter to your Twig variable:
>
> ```
> {% set myVar = '{baseUrl}/contact-us' %}
>
> {{ myVar | envvar }}
> ```