# Getting environmental variable via plugin

Tags: config, variable, environmentvariables

A [similar question was answered before](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/grab-environmentvariables-with-a-tag), but I was wonder how I might be able to return the same query from within a plugin (php)?

**Convert this:**

```
{{ craft.config.environmentVariables.baseUrl }}
```

**To something like this**: *(not correct)*

```
return craft()->config->get('environmentVariables.baseUrl');
```

What would be the correct syntax?

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
return craft()->config->get('environmentVariables')['baseUrl'];
```

Comment: For older versions of PHP:
var enVar = craft()->config->get('environmentVariables'); return enVar['baseUrl'];